# Python doesn't write into array

Tags: python, arrays, python-multiprocessing

I have an assignment, in which 5 different child process must write their number ID (1 to 5) into a shared array.
I managed to get my program to print out the child's number, however, when I print out the array it comes out empty.
What's wrong with my code?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Array, Semaphore
import random, time
import os

LUGARES  =  32
barco = Array("i",[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])


mutex = Semaphore(1)
vazio = Semaphore(LUGARES) #Inicialmente, LUGARES (32) posicoes livres  

def bilhetes(agencia):
    lotacao = 0
    while lotacao < LUGARES:
        vazio.acquire() 
        mutex.acquire()
        lugar = i + 1
        lotacao += 1
        barco[lugar] = agencia
        print barco[lugar] ,
        lugar = (lugar + 1)
        mutex.release()
        time.sleep(random.randint(0,1))



 for i in range(5):
    agencia = i + 1
    pid = os.fork()

    if pid == 0:
        bilhetes(agencia)       
        os._exit(0)



for i in range(0,32):   
    print barco[i]
```

Sample output (`barco`):

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Expected output:

```
54321 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 4 5 3 2 1 4 4
```

Comment: You appear to be using `os.fork()`, not the `multiprocessing` module.  With `fork()` each child process will modify its own local copy of the Array, it is not shared.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not use `Process` you have imported, instead, you are playing with `os.fork()`.

For me, this is the first time I see some usage of `os.fork()` and it looks rather tricky to do the job with it - there would be multiple processes - and these do not have shared access to variables so you would have to serialize and deserialize data across them.

Better use `multiprocessing` which has excellent API for this purpose, I would recommend you very nice tutorial from [Python Module of the Week: Multiprocessing - basics](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html) to learn about starting/stopping the processes, and then next a bit more advanced one [Communication between processes](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html).

Comment: Thanks for the links! 
I actually managed to get it right using forks (or at least  I think I did, because now it prints everything into the array). 
I can show you the final code if you care to see it